# How to prevent macOS Sierra from resetting manually set brightness?

Tags: macos, mac, brightness, display-settings, reset

On both my 2015 Macbook Pro and 2012 MacBook Air (Sierra) brightness changes (usually to a brighter level) from what I had set it (sometimes as soon as 5 minutes ago).

Auto adjust brightness is turned off. I am not using any app or plugin that may adjust brightness. In fact most of the time it happens when I am not even using some video player or media app (just in case that can change it).

How to make OSX keep the brightness at the level I manually set it to?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that it was dimming while under battery power. Try turning it that off under

System Preferences
Energy Saver
Battery
disable "Slightly dim the display while on battery power"